# Wireguard (Client) not working with Windows IP forwarding turned on

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing, wireguard

I have an issue using WireGuard client on windows. When I'm trying to connect to WireGuard server, there are no pings, no domain resolves - nothing. WireGuard shows that I do send like a 1GB/sec of packets. Also my PC starts to freeze, even tho there is no load on CPU/HDD/RAM etc. Android, and even Linux VM working inside Windows are working just fine.

If I set IPEnableRouter to 0 in regedit, everything works fine. If I disable forwarding for interface with "netsh interface ipv4 set interface *** forwarding=disabled" everything works fine. However, I'm looking for another solution as this one is unacceptable, as it disables routing between interfaces.

```
2022-03-19 18:59:47.241: [TUN] [PC] Monitoring MTU of default v6 routes 
2022-03-19 18:59:47.241: [TUN] [PC] Setting device v6 addresses 
2022-03-19 18:59:47.244: [TUN] [PC] Warning: the "Ethernet" interface has Forwarding/WeakHostSend enabled, which will cause routing loops 
2022-03-19 18:59:47.339: [TUN] [PC] Startup complete 
2022-03-19 19:00:02.211: [TUN] [PC] Retrying handshake with peer 1 (3.***.***.93:1**2) because we stopped hearing back after 15 seconds 
2022-03-19 19:00:02.211: [TUN] [PC] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (3.***.***.93:1**2) 
2022-03-19 19:00:07.357: [TUN] [PC] Handshake for peer 1 (3.***.***.93:1**2) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2) 
2022-03-19 19:00:07.357: [TUN] [PC] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (3.***.***.93:1**2) 
2022-03-19 19:00:12.415: [TUN] [PC] Handshake for peer 1 (3.***.***.93:1**2) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 3) 
2022-03-19 19:00:12.415: [TUN] [PC] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (3.***.***.93:1**2) 
2022-03-19 19:00:17.531: [TUN] [PC] Handshake for peer 1 (3.***.***.93:1**2) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 4) 
2022-03-19 19:00:17.531: [TUN] [PC] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (3.***.***.93:1**2)
2022-03-19 19:00:18.544: [TUN] [PC] Retrying handshake with peer 1 (3.***.***.93:1**2) because we stopped hearing back after 15 seconds 
2022-03-19 19:00:24.432: [TUN] [PC] Handshake for peer 1 (3.***.***.93:1**2) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)

and so on
```

Oh, and other VPN solutions like OpenVPN are working fine. The problem is with the WireGuard

Answer (score 2):

Warning: the has Forwarding/WeakHostSend enabled, which will cause routing loops

See [Alex Moore](https://serverfault.com/questions/929081/how-can-i-enable-packet-forwarding-on-windows) answer. Helped me

```
Get-NetIPInterface | select ifIndex,InterfaceAlias,AddressFamily,ConnectionState,Forwarding | Sort-Object -Property IfIndex | Format-Table

Set-NetIPInterface -ifindex <required interface index from table> -Forwarding Disabled
```

Comment: Yes, I know about that and even wrote command that you can use to disable it. However, Its not even nearly the solution, as there is no point in router that can't foward packets.